# override the default user plone.app.async runs its jobs

Tags: security, asynchronous, plone

I'm using `plone.app.async` to offload tasks to specific workers while the front-end workers are serving pages as fast as possible.

`plone.app.async` runs the async tasks with the same user that created the task, so I'm doing the following to be able to override it:

```
from AccessControl.SecurityManagement import newSecurityManager
from plone.app.async import Job
from plone.app.async import queue
from zope.component.hooks import getSite

site = getSite()
root = site.getPhysicalRoot()
admin_user = root.acl_users.getUserById('admin')

newSecurityManager(None, admin_user)
job = Job(
    some_random_task,
    parameter1,
    parameter2,
)
queue(job)
```

But it feels *hacky*...

The problem is that an external script (no control over it unfortunately) is sending data to our website to create objects on it, and thus needs quite a few permissions to be able to create, move, change workflow status and so on.

Is there a better way to override the user that `plone.app.async` uses?